# Can I use any micro USB cable to connect wireless Xbox One controller to PC?

Tags: pc, controllers, xbox-one

I found that you can't connect your regular Xbox One controller to my PC using the Charge and Play kit since the cable only provides power and no data transfer. So I bought a "wired" Xbox One controller for $60 (regular is $50) and found out it's pretty much the same controller with a standard Micro USB cable.

So my question is, next time can I just buy a regular Xbox One controller, which saves me a lot of money, and use my cellphone's micro USB cable to connect it to my PC?

Comment: You may need to download additional drivers: http://support.xbox.com/en-CA/xbox-one/accessories/controller-pc-compatibility

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can. You can use any regular Micro USB cable to connect an Xbox One controller to a PC.

Comment: Well that's 10 bucks down the drain for just a cable...

Comment: I'm actually surprised the Charge & Play kit's USB cable *doesn't* work. Even the USB cable included with the PS4 (used to charge the DS4 controller) can be used to connect an Xbox One controller to a PC (I'm using one right now)

Comment: Didn't work with the 360 and with the one. Didnt check but the salesman told me

Comment: The 360's play & charge was just power, no data. The One's play & charge is both data and power... I regularly play with the cable from my kit with no battery at all in my controller, since that makes it much lighter.

Comment: Eben, I have a wireless X360 controller and play and charge kit. I get that it's only power, but the charger's behavior is drastically different if I use a power socket (e.g. charger or the like) instead of a USB port of my pc. It charges faster (and the red light comes on) only when connected to PC. Which is just ridiculous if it has no data transfer.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the cable.  The cable that I use to connect my wireless controller to my PC broke, so I thought, "No problem, I'll just use the cable I charge my phone with since I know that can pass data as well as power."  While it was able to power the controller, it wasn't able to send data for some reason.  I plugged the controller in using the cable that my headset came with and it worked.  Out of curiosity, I plugged the cable I charge my phone with into my headset to see if it would send power and data...  And it did.  No idea why the cable didn't work with the controller.

Answer (score 0):

My Xbox One controller with the original Play & Charge cable that it came with is the only cable that would work for me on my PC.. Now I know that they take Micro-B cables, so that explains why my long micro-USB cable wouldn't work at all for using my Xbox One controller with my PC... But just make sure you buy a micro-B (has to be B) cable and it will work.

IDK why your P&C cable doesn't work, it's the only one I could get to work with mine lol

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem as you, in my case it was because the rechargeable battery was still attached to the controller.

Try removing the battery pack, this fixed it for me.